# Path to stylesheet not updating on WordPress?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

After making frequent edits to my stylesheet on WordPress Avada child theme (either through the custom CSS editor in Avada or SiteOrigin CSS plugin) the website will randomly lose access to the stylesheet. Sometimes a couple of pages, sometimes the whole site is loaded without formatting

I have found that Chrome is throwing the

```
Refused to apply style from <path> because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled
```

However, I do not believe that it is caused by the stylesheet starting with a comment as mentioned in other posts related to this error.

When I go to my file manager and follow the path shown in the error, the .min.css file that it is pointing to is not there. I have solved the issue by downloading the most recently edited stylesheet (there are usually 2 or 3) and renaming it to the file that Chrome inspector shows in the error.

Expected result: site automatically updates the path to the latest .min.css file

Actual result: the site will not point to the correct file, but only occasionally/randomly.

Two main questions:

1. Is there something I am doing incorrectly to cause this (editing too fast, editing through plugins, etc.)
2. Once this error occurs, how can I tell my site to go look at the latest style sheet?

Answer (score 0):

Strict MIME type checking is a security feature that can be activated by sending the HTTP Header `X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff` to the client, see 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Content-Type-Options .

Clients that respect this header must only rely on the MIME type sent by the server, so you have to make sure that CSS files are served with the correct header, which seems not to be the case with some wordpress setups, probably by a plugin that optimizes style and script files.

If you able to edit your server's `.htaccess` file(assuming a typical wordpress installation on an Apache webserver), you could try add a Set-Header directive like:
`AddType text/css .css`